# Aptana 3 auto compile coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript, aptana

Using Aptana3, is it possible to auto compile the .coffee files when I save them or when I run the project, with some specifics rules (like where the output should go, if I can compress files into one, etc) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-cw` flag with `coffee` in console for example:

```
coffee -cw file.coffee
```

this will watch file `file.coffee` for changes and compile it. You can use more options just run

```
coffee --help
```

comand for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to do it:
Say your work is in "my-project-path" folder.

1. Go to the parent folder of "my-project-path"
2. Start a terminal and type `coffee -o my-project-path -cw my-project-path`

This line will watch and compile anything name as "*.coffee" in "my-project-path" folder, even if it is in "my-project-path/scripts/core" or "my-project-path/test/core".The js file will locate in the save folder as the .coffee file.